# How can I get this integral to Compute

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I'm trying to compute the following expression and get an analytical answer but Mathematica ends up spitting back the input expression. Hoping someone can shine some light on this.

```
Integrate[(0.5*exp^(-(y^2/(2*sigy^2)) - (exp^(i*y) - z)^2/(exp^(2*i*y)*(2*sigx^2))))/(exp^(i*y)*(pi^1.*sigx*sigy)), {y, -pi, pi}]}
```

Attaching traditional integration expression below

[image]

Comment: First thing to note would be that pi is Pi in Mathematica and i is I and exp is Exp. That is, first thing to do is to learn some basics, and then try again.

Comment: @MichaelWeyrauch is right. However, I tried the integral in Mma and it does not evaluate. Maybe the OP should give a reason that an analytic result is expected?

Comment: Doubt `Integrate` will work for this integrand. You should look at `NIntegrate`.